# When to use Option in Scala and when not to

Tags: scala, null, option-type

so Lets say I have some class:

```
case class Product(id: Int, name: String)
```

If I'm interfacing with some Java API or something and the possibility of either of those values being null is there then could I just write:

```
case class Product(id: Option[Int], name: Option[String])
```

If I wasn't interfacing with anything that has nulls as a concept then it would be fine to just stick with the first implementation right?
It seems a little annoying because I would have to write unit tests to test these things as well...

Thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question when to use Option should be more related to the fact that a value could be missing as opposed to a value might be mistakenly set to null.

To clarify, if you're worried that somehow the user of your library could set the `id` or `name` field to null, you should check for it in both version. Indeed `Option` itself doesn't give you any guarantee.

Furthermore using an Option where on a value that is not really optional is really misleading.

I usually use `Option` only to explicitly declare that a value might not be present and that is a valid state.

When it comes to interacting with Java I adopt the following 2 strategies depending if I'm providing the API or consuming it:

1. If I provide an API that is consumed by Java code I **don't** use `Option`, but instead use a little constructor wrapper which check that all parameters are not null and throw and `IllegalArgumentException` otherwise.
2. If I consume an API written in Java I **do** use `Option` wrapping all returned value so that my Scala code can handle these cases in a cleaner way.

Comment: Great advice, I would agree with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use `require` to throw `IllegalArgumentException`, for example:

`case class Product(id: Int, name: String){ 
  require(name != null, "the name cannot be null")
}`